# Custom Toolbar Contents Being Cut Off On Certain Devices

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm having an issue with custom toolbars in my app:
[image: Example]

This only seems to happen on certain devices, for example my personal phone does not have this issue, but a Pixel Emulator on 7.1.1 has this issue.

For reference here is the code I am using.

XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_nav"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/titleContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="50dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fwLogo"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:foregroundGravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/nav_logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:text="Baby And You"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</FrameLayout>
```

Java (although, not sure if this is relevant or not):

```
Toolbar action = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(action);
setTitle("");

int statusBarHeight = 0;
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}

final TypedArray styledAttributes = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{android.R.attr.actionBarSize});
int actionSize = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.recycle();

int height = statusBarHeight + actionSize;

action.setLayoutParams(new  FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));
```

And finally here is the layout inspector:
[image: Layout inspector]

So far I have tried, manually setting the height, changing the height to wrap content (bizzarly, both resulted in the correct proportions but the text disappeared) and setting a `minHeight` (which had no effect).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried your code on my Pixel Emulator with 7.1.1 and it worked fine

Comment: Interesting. I might try it in a new activity, in case something else is affecting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was happening - the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attribute was causing these issues. I simply added some manual padding and removed this attribute and everything began working perfectly.